# GitHub Fork Projects

Tags: git, github

I have been working on a project in an organization on GitHub with a team. I want to fork this project to make my own modifications but the problem is when I submit a pull request to the forked repository is also shown in the original repository?

How can I fix that and make the pr goes to my only forked project?

Answer (score 0):

When you first create a PR, you should be able to see the available repositories to which you can make your PR:

[image: Avaiable repositories]

If you don't see the available repositories, you could also click on "compare across forks" to show them.

[image: Compare across forks]

Lastly, you could also manually modify the first part of your URL to point to the repository to which you want to make your PR:

[image: URL]